# Blue underlines under clickable images and links in Wordpress themes - How to remove?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

I have these blue underlines beneath links and clickable images on my WordPress site. Just wondering how I can remove these. Pic below. Using Elementor builder. Thank you.

[image]